# firefox adds strange space arround Pseudo-elements

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-element

Take a look at these photos
**JSFiddle** link at the bottom

firefox:
[image]
chrome:
[image]

they are both the same element taken from chrome and firefox and as you can see the one from firefox has some space around it's top and left side but the one from chrome doesn't 
now, There is no margin or anything that's causing this and it works fine in any other browser except for firefox.
the important styles for the main element is

```
float: left; 
height: 30px; 
line-height: 30px; 
margin: 12.5px 0;
```

and for the  Pseudo-element ::before

```
float: left; 
display: block;
content: '\F011'; 
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
margin: 0 10px 0 0; 
padding: 0 10px;
```

and the HTML for the element

```
<button class="like" onclick="item_like()">500</button>
```

this is the link of JSFiddle 
run it in chrome and firefox and see the difference
http://jsfiddle.net/79cEb/5/
what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Firefox seems to add a little default space around your content within the button. Have you tried including normalize.css ? This is a special css file that tries to make browser styling consistent. http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: as [Laurens Kling](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1192584/laurens-kling) commented, one easy way to do this is to use normalize.css http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/<br>
it worked fine :)
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try positioning the like absolutely using CSS

```
.like{
float: left; 
height: 30px; 
margin: 12.5px 0; 
background-color: #FAFAFA; 
border-radius: 4px; 
position:relative;
padding: 0 10px 0 40px; 
margin: 12.5px 10px; 
background-color: #000; 
font: 16px/30px arial; 
color: #FFF; 
border:none;}

.like::before{
position:absolute; top:0; left:0; 
width:30px; 
content: 'like'; 
margin: 0 10px 0 0; 
padding: 0 5px;
background-color: #FF7373; 
color: #FFF; 
border-right: 1px solid #CCC; display:block; border:0;
}
```

Comment: This will then need top and bottom border radius adding again e.g `border-top-left-radius:4px;`

Comment: yes, this will work but it requires editing all my css, and I'm to lazy to do that. but normalize.css did work for me

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to specify top:0; left: 0; to your ::before pseudo elements. Sometimes cheeky browsers take a few px up and left to the actual position. CSS:

```
.like:before {
    float: none;
    width: 30px;
    content: "like";
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    background-color: #FF7373;
    color: #FFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
.like {
    float: none;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    margin: 12.5px 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    font: 16px/30px arial;
    color: #FFF;
    border: medium none;
    position: relative;
    width: 88px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/79cEb/13/

Answer (score 0):

I made you this solution, it places the button relative and the `:before` class absolute. Then you can use the `top`, `bottom` and `left` position, which will be relative to parent.

Note that I added a `overflow: hidden` to the button, so the rounded borders are still visible.

This is the altered CSS:

```
.like {
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 12.5px 0;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 0 10px 0 40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 12.5px 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    font: 16px/30px arial;
    color: #FFF;
    border:none;
    position: relative;
}
.like::before {
    float: left;
    width:30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content:'\F011';
    background-color: #FF7373;
    color: #FFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Also, see the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/79cEb/10/).